# recover WPA2 passphrase from iPhone4s or its backup?

Tags: wifi

I forgot the passphrase to a WiFi network but my phone still connects to it.

My old iPhone3 used to be connected there, then when I migrated to an iPhone4S the settings were magically transferred through iTunes. I guess the WPA2 key is therefore in the backups (which are not encrypted)

Is there a way to recover this WPA2 key from either the phone directly or from the backups? I read that there is an app for jailbroken phones but mine is not.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your WiFi network?  If not, can't you just ask for the password again?

Comment: @Nathan: you mean to take the simple solution? :) In fact this is my WiFi network I installed at my parent's place on a tomato router. I have long forgotten all the credentials by now, including the router admin and the WPA key. The system is far away and if you have ever supported computer-impaired family you know that doing a remote reset of a router is something which one wants to avoid at all price :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind jailbreaking your phone, there's an app called “Wi-Fi Passwords” in Cydia that displays the Wi-Fi networks you've connected to and their passwords.